# Porque o sass e less não funcionam no PowerShell?

Tags: node.js, windows, sass, powershell, less

Instalei o sass e less através do node.js(globalmente, assim como exemplificado nos sites das ferramentas em questão). Usei ambas no cmd sem problemas, mas ao tentar no PowerShell, recebi a seguinte menssagem:

**sass(lessc) : File C:\Users\u\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass(lessc).ps1 cannot be loaded.

The file 
C:\Users\u\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass(lessc).ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system.

For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

At line:1 char:1

- lessc
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess**
  ```

Qual o motivo disso? Há como resolver?

OBS: node.js v14.2.0 instalado pelo chocolatey.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema está relacionado as politicas de segurança do Powershell.

Por padrão a politica de execução não é definida(undefined).
Quando a politica não é definica, o powershell assume a política restrita(restricted).

Você pode conferir a documentação [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7).

Pra contornar esse problema, basta alterar a politica de executação rodando o script abaixo:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```