# Erro na execução de comandos expo no powershell

Tags: powershell, expo

Estou me arriscando no React Native e acontece que quando vou tentar executar o comando `expo init`, ou mesmo `expo --version` através do PowerShell fica dando o seguinte erro:

```
expo : 
  O arquivo C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.ps1 não pode ser carregado. 
  O arquivo
C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.ps1 não está assinado digitalmente.
  Não é possível executar este script no sistema atual. 
  Para obter mais informações sobre como executar scripts e definir a 
   política de execução, consulte about_Execution_Policies at
   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

No linha:1 caractere:1
+ expo --version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ErrodeSegurança: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Acontece que pelo antigo cmd o comando é executado, e através de algumas consultas aqui e ali eu descobri como alterar as políticas de proteção de script, então alterei para bypass e ele executa, porém acredito que deixo assim meu computador vulnerável, então pergunto: como adiciono o expo como uma exceção para que ele possa ser executado, pois mesmo com o AllSigned ele não responde aos comandos!

Comment: Tem resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452931/porque-o-sass-e-less-n%c3%a3o-funcionam-no-powershell)

Comment: Uma forma mais segura para não deixar seu computador vulnerável é fazendo o Bypass apenas para a sessão atual do PowerShell com o seguinte comando (executando como administrador):

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process`

Dessa maneira quando você fechar o PowerShell essa ExecutionPolicy será consequentemente removido.

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema e a solução encontrada com facilidade foi de alterar a politica de execução mas como você disse corretamente deixa o computador vulnerável. A solução que encontrei foi utilizar o **npm start** ao invés do expo start, claro desde que o expo esteja instalado e funciona perfeitamente o log do powershell ficou assim:

PS C:\Users\super\multiInstagram> **npm start**

@ start C:\Users\super\multiInstagram
expo start

Starting project at C:\Users\super\multiInstagram
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Starting Metro Bundler

exp://192.168.0.100:19000

Você pode consultar a documentação do Expo no link abaixo, no item Starting the development server:

When you run expo start (**or npm start**), Expo CLI starts Metro Bundler, which is an HTTP server that compiles the JavaScript code of our app using Babel and serves it to the Expo app. It also pops up Expo Dev Tools, a graphical interface for Expo CLI.

fonte: https://docs.expo.io/get-started/create-a-new-app/#starting-the-development-server

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão o powerShell tem algumas verificações de segurança que impedem ele de rodar scripts não assinados

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

Para burlar utilize esse comando

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, apareceu depois de atualizar o node. Nenhum comando ( npx, npm, expo star etc.) funcionava. Ai eu desistalei totalmente o node e instalei novamente. Ai deu certo.